# AtrributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data' & TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, python-idle

I am trying to get weather information from a town, and have 2 items print out from that list. However, when i try to run the code, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
    File "/home/pi/Desktop/python/PyWeather.py" line 4, in <module>
        bostonweather = pywapi.get_weather_from_weather_com('UKXX1701', units = 'metric')
    File "/home/pi/Desktop/python/pywapi.py" line 239, in get_weather_from_weather_com
        'wind')[0].getElementsByTagName(tag2)[0].firstChild.data
AtrributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'
```

This is my code:

```
import pywapi
import string

bostonweather = pywapi.get_weather_from_weather_com('UKXX1701', 'metric')
print ("In Boston, Lincolnshire it is currently: ") + string.ascii_lowercase(bostonweather['current_conditions']['text'] + (" and ") + string.ascii_lowercase(bostonweather['current_conditions']['temperature'] + ("C.\n"))
```

//EDIT

I've just reran my program and it just threw a "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable" error instead.
Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/pi/Desktop/python/PyWeather.py" line 5, in <module>  
       print ("In Boston, Lincolnshire it is currently: ") + string.ascii_lowercase(bostonweather['current_conditions']['text'] + (" and ") + string.ascii_lowercase(bostonweather['current_conditions']['temperature'] + ("C.\n"))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Any clue on what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make all strings before you print

```
import pywapi

bostonweather = pywapi.get_weather_from_weather_com('UKXX1701', 'metric')
print ("In Boston, Lincolnshire it is currently: " + str(bostonweather['current_conditions']['text']).lower() + " and " + str(bostonweather['current_conditions']['temperature']).lower())
```

Comment: This still gives me a `Typeerror: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'` :(

EDIT: Nevermind! I removed some brackets from the strings like in your code, and it worked :) Thanks!

Comment: Not sure why it's giving you errors, I checked it with python3.4 and it's good. I guess your interpreter has a different version, but anyway I'm glad you fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call `string.lowercase(blabla)` and that's where you get `TypeError`

You should do

```
print "In Boston, Lincolnshire it is currently: " + bostonweather['current_conditions']['text'].lower() + " and " + bostonweather['current_conditions']['temperature'].lower() + ("C.\n")
```

Comment: I tried this but now I get this error:  
`Typeerror: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'`